# Log Analitics query for summarized dau wise all http errors count

Tags: http, https, azure-log-analytics

We have a requirement in our project to get day-wise http error count (http 4xx, 5xx) using Azure Log-Analytics.

```
Day     http 403   http 404   http 500   http 502   http ?   total_error_count
18-Dec  2          0          1          2          1        6
19-Dec  3          4          1          1          1        10
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow. :)

You would have to leverage [summarize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/summarizeoperator) operator, [timespan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/scalarfunctions#datetimetimespan-functions) function(s) and ([extend](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/extendoperator) operator if you have to create seperate columns for each http error code and append them to the result set).
Basic query would look something like shown below.

```
AAAA
| extend BBBB_column = xxxxxxx, CCCC_column = yyyyyyy
| summarize BBBB_count_column=count(BBBB_column), CCCC_count_column=count(CCCC_column) by date_column=dayofmonth(TimeGenerated)
| project date_column, BBBB_count_column, CCCC_count_column, sum_column=BBBB_count_column+CCCC_count_column
```

where AAAA is table name, xxxxxxx and yyyyyyy are some calculations to fetch particular http error codes respectively.

Hope this information helps! Cheers!